# Wordpress custom url and GET

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use custom url's in Wordpress.

http://example.com/home instead of http://example.com?page_id=home

But how I should use GET function now?

```
$page_id = $_GET['page_id'];
if($page_id == 'home') include 'home.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET` isn't a function, and you shouldn't use it. It contains values parsed from the query string, and you don't have one.

Parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like `http://localhost/wordpress/2012/01/hello-world/?g=1` this url. Result of `print_r($_GET)` for this url is `Array ( [g] => 1 )`.

But if you want to use custom url, you must change htaccess file. You can use following two options:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Long_Permalinks
- There are some plugins for these actions. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-htaccess-control/ , ...

Answer (score 0):

The 'WordPress way' to do this would be to register the `page_id` as a 'query variable' and use [`get_query_var`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var).

To register a query variable, you can use the `query_vars` filter. Put the following into your plugin or theme's `function.php`

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'register_my_query_vars' );
function register_my_query_vars( $qvars ){
    //Add these query variables - do not overwrite the $qvars array
    $qvars[] = 'page_id';    
    return $qvars;
}
```

Then you should be able to use `get_query_var('page_id')` to obtain its value (home, in the question).