# How to get value from url?

Tags: php

If I have url like this: `www.example.com/product/yellow-bed` is it possible to retrieve product name from url?
For example, if url would be like `www.example.com?page=product&product_name=yellow_bed` I would use:

```
$product = $_GET['page'];
$product_name = $_GET['product_name'];
```

But how to get it from `www.example.com/product/yellow-bed` ?

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/parse_url and http://php.net/parse_str and http://php.net/explode

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress custom url and GET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969212/wordpress-custom-url-and-get)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the URI by "$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]". Convert the string into an array with explode:

```
$uri = 'www.google.com/product/yellow-bed' //uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
$uriArray = explode('/', $uri);
$product = $urlArray[1];
$product_name = $urlArray[2];
```

0 = www.google.com, 1 = product, 2 = yellow-bed

PHP manual: [`array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php).

Comment: Why url and urlArray is without `$`?

Answer (score 1):

Some php frameworks (like CodeIgniter) has already this function implemented.
Never the less you can have a look here: http://erunways.com/simple-php-get-uri-or-segment-element/ , and that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch the complete URI with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and then split it apart. Or you work with an .htaccess and internally rewrite the url.

Comment: The `$_SERVER[ 'QUERY_STRING' ]` advice is completely wrong, since in the URL the OP wants to extract the data from -- `www.example.com/product/yellow-bed` -- there is no query string. @bratkartoffel is correct that if you wanted you could rewrite  that to a URL where `page` and `product_name` are query string variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$_SERVER[ 'PATH_INFO' ]` or `$_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. This will be `/product/yellow-bed` in your example.

You can then use `strrpos()`, `explode() or`preg_match()` (or other string manipulation functions) to extract what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following function to retrive current url:

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>
```

now you can take url and parse its elements using parse_url : http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: What the hell? He really only needs to parse the path, which is in `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`.